# How to get time() like value from mktime()

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$value = '2012-03-05';
$parts = explode('-',$value);
$value = mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],$parts[0],$parts[2]);

// output of $value is 2012
```

Shouldn't `mktime()` return output similar to `time()`?

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: the 5th argument is day, however you're passing the year in there. switch $parts[0] and $parts[2].

Comment: its always a good idea to post a minimal code snippet to demonstrate your problem. But, make sure it still demonstrates the problem after you've stripped all the other stuff out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use the `strtotime` function in order to convert a string representing a time to unix timestamp number

```
$value = "2012-05-25";
$time = strtotime($value." 00:00:00");
//$time = strtotime($value); will do the work as well
```

Comment: As a note, adding the " 00:00:00" is not necessary. `$time = strtotime("2012-05-25");` accomplishes the same.

Comment: I know, but still - when I write code like this I prefer to also mention the hour in order for it to be more readble and obvious

Answer (score 1):

Thats wrong use of [mktime](http://php.net/mktime). here **day comes before year** not after. Use this,

```
mktime(0,0,0,$parts[1],$parts[2],$parts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, mktime() should return a unix timestamp just like time() does. The code you posted doesn't properly represent the code you're executing if thats not the case.

heres a demo
http://codepad.org/7RNxk0Oz